# Detect when second tableview cell comes into view - then perform an action

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've got a `UITableView` in a `UIViewController`, as well as a filter button. I hide the filter button when the user starts to scroll down the list.  I want to then show the filter button when the second cell (`index 1`) is visible. However, I can't get this desired effect, I can only get it to appear when it reaches the top. Here is my code for when it reaches the top (I then show the filter button again).

```
//determines when the tableview was scrolled
-(void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
     //tableview is scrolled down
    if (currentOffset.y > self.lastContentOffset.y)
      {

    //if the showFilter button is visible i.e alpha is greater than 0
        if (self.showFilter.alpha==1.0) {

            [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{

                //hide show filter button
                self.showFilter.alpha=0.0;
                //I also adjust the frames of a tableview here
            }];

        }


    }


    //determines if it is scrolled back to the top
    if (self.showFilter.alpha==0.0 && currentOffset.y==0) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            //show filter button
            self.showFilter.alpha=1.0;

          //i also adjust the frames of the tableview here
        }];
    }

    self.lastContentOffset = currentOffset;
}
```

I have also tried:

```
if (self.showFilter.alpha==0.0 && currentOffset.y<160)
```

But it doesn't work to the desired effect as the tableview jumps off the screen. Is there another way to get this desired effect?

Comment: UITableView has a property on it called `visibleCells`, this contains an array of UITableViewCells that are currently visible. There is also an array of `NSIndexPaths called indexPathsForVisibleRows`.

Comment: Maybe Give a tag to your second cell and then if this cell will be displayed and the scrolling up then show filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A previous answer suggested that you should check if the cell is visible every time the table view scrolls (in `scrollViewDidScroll:`). However, you should not do this. That approach could affect the performance of your table view since a check must be performed every single time the table view scrolls.

Instead, you only need to check every time a new cell will become visible by implementing this `UITableViewDelegate` method:

```
- (void)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(nonnull UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([indexPath isEqual:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]]) {
        // perform action
    }
}
```

Prior to Swift 3 you would write the following:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath == NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0) {
        // perform action
    }
}
```

In Swift 3 or greater you would write the following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath == IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0) {
        // perform action
    }
}
```

In either case don't forget to set your `UIViewController` subclass as the `delegate` of the `UITableView`.

Comment: why do you pass in 'nonnull'? I've never seen this before.

Comment: @DevC Take a look at this Swift Blog article https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25